# Edit & Delete object with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've successfully implemented a viewmodel so I can create and return items from my database using two tables.  My issue is editing and deleting individual items.

I was able to edit/delete when I was using just one table, but with two, i've run into a snag.

My view uses a viewmodel now.  I am not able to figure out how to pass the specific object id when Passing an id and TransactionViewModel Viewmodel into my Edit method Parameters.

Here is my old Edit and Edit post.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Transactions transactions = _db.Transactions.Find(id);
        if (transactions == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(transactions);
    }

[HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(TransactionViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var transactionType = viewModel.Transaction.TransactionType;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //If the transaction category is an Expense, set it to a negative so we can calculate later.
            if (transactionType == Classes.Constants.Expense || (transactionType == Classes.Constants.Payment && viewModel.Transaction.Amount < 0))
            {
                viewModel.Transaction.Amount *= -1;
            }

            var transaction = new Transactions()
            {
                ClientId = viewModel.Transaction.ClientId,
                Amount = viewModel.Transaction.Amount,
                Date = viewModel.Transaction.Date,
                Category = viewModel.Transaction.Category,
                Description = viewModel.Transaction.Description,
                TransactionType = viewModel.Transaction.TransactionType
            };


            _db.Entry(transaction).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I've tried this for my get Edit, but it returns the same thing each time and not the one specified on my view.  Ex.  If click edit for Client D, it will pull up the edit screen for Client A and I cannot save it.  I have an edit and delete button in my viewable table next to each transaction using an @Html.ActionLink().

```
 public ActionResult Edit(TransactionViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var transactions = from t in _db.Transactions
                               join c in _db.Clients
                                   on t.ClientId equals c.ClientId
                               select new TransactionViewModel() { Clients = c, Transaction = t };

            return View(transactions.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? What do you mean it returns the same object

Comment: Perhaps ModelState.IsValid is returning false?

Comment: I updated my post.  By same object, if I click the edit button for a client, it will load the first client in my edit view, not the one I specified.  This may be due to me using FirstorDefault in my LINQ query, but I need to only return one object in my IEnumberable.

Comment: Where are you specifying the client to get the FirstOrDefault for? I may be wrong but it looks like it is going to pull the first record of all clients joined with their transactions.

Comment: I'm specifying the FirstOrDefault in my return View(transactions.FirstOrDefault()) for my Edit method in my controller.

Comment: I see that, but shouldn't you also have a and c.ClientID equals "some value"?

Answer (score 0):

I bet that view is being cached. There are many different ways to influence caching in the controller. If you want to simply remove cacheing, in your case for editing, then decorate that action with the following:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult Edit(TransactionViewModel viewModel)

[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
```

Note: You will have to clear cache to get the new view with the no cache set above.

Comment: Did you hit F12 tools and clear cache for domain. It could be holding the old version. If that does not work then it is not a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Get Edit method should still accept an int ID to select the correct record form the database and it should return the view model.

something like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{

    var transactions = from t in _db.Transactions
                               join c in _db.Clients
                                   on t.ClientId equals c.ClientId
                   where t.id == id
                               select new TransactionViewModel() { Clients = c, Transaction = t };

    return View(transactions.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Comment: I'm able to access the edit view, but again, it loads the same client information for every single transaction.

Comment: When debugging the Get Edit method, what do you have in the transaction collection object? Is you data in the database correct?